Formatting excel output from pandas for font size, color etc for all sheets
I am writing out multiple dataframes to a excel workbook. I want to change the default font to  "century Gothic" and size to 9 and color to blue (font color 2659D9) for all the sheets.
I also want the numbers column to have an accounting format and the date columns to have yyyy-mm-dd format. I tried the code below, but it is not working.
Executable code below:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'JDate':["2022-01-31","2022-12-05","2023-11-10","2023-12-03","2024-01-16","2024-01-06","2011-01-04"],
        # 'Month':[1,12,11,12,1,1],
        'Code':[None,'John Johnson',np.nan,'John Smith','Mary Williams','ted bundy','George Lucas'],
        'Unit Price':[np.nan,200,None,56,75,65,60],
        'Quantity':[1500, 140000, 1400000, 455, 648, 759,1000],
        'Amount':[100, 10000, 100000, 5, 48, 59,449],
        'Invoice':['soccer','basketball','baseball','football','baseball','ice hockey','football'],
        'energy':[100.,100,100,54,98,3,45],
        'Category':['alpha','bravo','kappa','alpha','bravo','bravo','kappa']
})

df["JDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["JDate"])

df["JYearMonth"] =  df['JDate'].dt.to_period('M')


index_to_use = ['Category','Code','Invoice','Unit Price']
values_to_use = ['Amount']
columns_to_use = ['JYearMonth']


df2 = df.pivot_table(index=index_to_use,
                            values=values_to_use,
                            columns=columns_to_use)


df3 = df2.xs('alpha',level='Category')
df3 = df3.reset_index() 


writer= pd.ExcelWriter(
        "t2test13.xlsx",
        engine='xlsxwriter'
    )


df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="t2",index=True)
df2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="t2test",index=True)
df3.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="t2filter",index=True)

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets["t2"]

fmt_header = workbook.add_format({
    'bold':True,
    'text_wrap':True,
    'valign':'top',
    'fg_color': '#5DADE2',
    'font_color':'#2659D9',
    'border':1
})


writer.close()


You could change that section to something like the following to write the dataframe and change the header formatting at the same time.

Since there are merged cells and multi row Headers I have changed the code.
Code sample now using Openpyxl to do the formatting in Excel.
Not sure if your use of 'fmt_header' was just because you copied that from the tutorial or you do want this format for the Header only and another format for the rest of the data.
I have applied two different formats in this example.
The Header formatting is applied to all Sheets, Headers is considered to be the number of rows the Dataframe Header covers i.e. first 1 or 2 rows. This duplicates the 'fmt_header' formatting and is applied as Named Style. If a Named Style is not desired the formatting can be applied to each cell separately.
I have set the rest of the data formatting to just Font name='Century Gothic' and size=9.
If you want this formatting to be the same as the header you can simply remove the criteria checks for Headers and add the defined name to all cells.
Any column with the Header Name 'JDate' number_format is changed to 'yyyy-mm-dd', excluding the Header row(s).
See example screen shots below
...

df3 = df3.reset_index() <-- My Code Changes are from after this line to end of file

### Create a Named Style to set the Header Formatting
header_fmt = NamedStyle(name="header_fmt")
header_fmt.font = Font(bold=True, name='Century Gothic', size=9)
header_fmt.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='top', wrapText=True)
header_fmt.fill = PatternFill(start_color='5DADE2', end_color='5DADE2', fill_type='solid')
bd = Side(style='medium', color="000000")
header_fmt.border = Border(left=bd, top=bd, right=bd, bottom=bd)

### Create dictionary of Sheet to Dataframe
sheet_names = {"t2": df, "t2test": df2, "t2filter": df3}

with pd.ExcelWriter('t2test13.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    ### Add the named style to the workbook
    writer.book.add_named_style(header_fmt)
    ### Use a loop to write the dataframe and set that dataframe header formatting
    for sheet, dataframe in sheet_names.items():
        dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, index=True)
        worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet]
        
        date_idx = 0  # Index of the column with JDate if it exists otherwise its 0
        if 'JDate' in dataframe.columns:
            ### The '+2' offsets the inclusion of the Index and that with ExcelWriter first column number is 0 and Openpyxl it's 1
            date_idx = dataframe.columns.get_loc("JDate") + 2

        ### Iterate all cells in the data and add formatting as needed    
        for row in worksheet.iter_rows():
            for cell in row:
                if cell.row <= dataframe.columns.nlevels:  # Header rows only
                    ### Update the column headers with the named style
                    ### The Header is considered to be the number of rows in the dataframe header
                    cell.style = header_fmt
                    if isinstance(cell, openpyxl.cell.cell.Cell):  # Widen columns for viewability
                        worksheet.column_dimensions[cell.column_letter].width = 12
                else:  # All other rows
                    if cell.column == date_idx:  # If this is a Date column change number_format
                        cell.number_format = "yyyy-mm-dd"
                    cell.font = Font(name='Century Gothic', size=9, bold=False, color='000000')


Example Sheets
All Sheets headers are formatted the same including font name "Century Gothic" and size 9. 
Rest of the data is formatted to font name "Century Gothic" and size 9 only with 'JDate' column number_format set to 'yyyy-mm=dd' for non header rows.
You can see the Named Style applied to the workbook in the top right of the t2 screen shot.


this will just format header or the entire worksheet? I want to format the whole worksheets, not just the header

Updated the code to format all the cells. Not sure if you meant to use the same formatting for all cells, I have used different formatting for Headers and other cells as detailed in the answer and this can be changed to apply same format to all data if you choose or modify the formatting as you need.

thanks, so opepyxl is the better choice than xlsxwriter?

With Xlsxwriter you apply the format for a cell with the write statement, i.e. as you write the cell values you also apply the formatting. Although its under consideration applying formatting separately with Xlsxwriter is not possible at this time. A helper module does exist to support it, 'XlsxPandasFormatter' but not tried it so cannot comment how good an option it might be. In this case we are using to_excel to write the dataframe to the sheet in one go, so the values are there already and we do need to apply the formatting to the cells afterwards. Therefore Openpyxl is the [only] choice.

You can apply a certain amount of styling with Pandas itself so the formatting is applied with the cells as written with to_excel. These methods have limitations so additional formatting after the dataframe is transcribed would probably still be needed so it makes sense to just switch to Openpyxl and use it for all the formatting.
